# Select only recent updated rows in MySQL db with a large data volume

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working with a InnoDB table that contains up to 30000 records. Rows are updated frequenty with stock_quantity value. What i need to do is to select only the most recent updated rows with a scheduled task and perform some actions thru a WebService.

Just trying to understand which is the best way for doing this without kill performance. I'm thinking at 3 different solution:

1. using a *datetime* column and update its value on each modify. Then select rows where date_col > NOW()-20 min. (20 min. is the frequency crontab is running)
2. using a boolean column and set the value to true each time the row is modified. Then select rows where boolean_col is true. If the task is executed set back the value of boolean_col to false.
3. using a second table to store recent updated columns. On each update of a row in table_1 copy the row to table_2. Then select all rows from table_2, perform actions and truncate table_2.

Anyway I'm pretty sure the right solution is not listed up there... so does anyone have some good advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fist at all,
30,000 record is not that big ...

i prefer method 1 with some additional changes

- set the datetime column default to `on update current_timestamp`
- build an index of this column

method 2 will incurred redundant write, and read

method 3 is the worse, it almost `double x double` the write and read operations

Comment: I agree with you on using method #1, but I'd like to note that making the datetime column an index which gets changed every now and then will lead to index fragmentation.. However, it shouldn't be an issue if the index gets defragmented\rebuilt on a schedule too..

Comment: @ajreal: thanks for the advice! I was already thinking about 'on update current_timestamp' but not at the index. So, there's not a better method besides this 3?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use your option 2.

I would seriously look at a tigger to set the value to 1 if the row is edited. Of course excluding and update that only effect the boolean col.

I would then have the cron search the table when boolean = 1, return the list process the file and update the field back to 0 once complete.

This would be my approach, but like you said there might be a better way.

Another Idea:  You might also want to look at replacing your cron with the tigger and preform the action your cron does on record update might work...